# Pandas Value Error (columns passed) No matter how many columns passed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making a pandas df based on a list and a 3D list of lists. If you want to see the whole code, you can look here: https://github.com/Bigglesworth95/Fish-Food-Calculator/blob/main/foodDataScraper.py

but I will do my best to summarize below. (If you want to peruse the code and offer any recommendations, I will happily accept tho. I'm a noob and I know I'm not good at this :)

1. The lists I am using here are quite long. IDK if that makes much of a difference but I thought I would note it since I won't be posting the full contents of the lists below for this reason.

2)The function to make the df is as follows:

```
def make_df ():
    counter = 0
    nameLength = len(names)
    print('nameLength =', nameLength)
    for product in newTupledList:
        templist = []
        if counter <= nameLength:
            templist.append(names[counter])
        product.insert(0, templist)
        counter += 1

    df1 = pd.DataFrame (newTupledList, columns=['Name','Crude Protein', 'Crude Fat', 'Crude Fiber', 'Moisture'...])
    return df1
```

2. newTupledList is a list that looks like this: [[['Crude Protein', '48%'], ['Crude Fat', '5.5%'], ['Crude Fiber', '0.5%'], ['Moisture', '6%'], ['Phosphorus', '0.1%']...]...]

Note that the first layer is all the products, the second is the individual product, and the third is all the nutritional values of all products, populated with data for the individual products and then a 0 for everything not relevant.

3. Len of names is 24. IDK if its relevant.

Now, the interesting issue here is that, no matter how many columns I pass in the dF I get a value error. If I do nothing, then I get a value error saying that I only passed 52 columns and needed 60. If I add 8 more columns it will say that I passed 60 columns but needed 61. If I add one to that it will say I passed 61 columns but needed 60. And so on.

Has anyone ever seen anything like that happen before? What are some approaches I could take to debugging such a weird bug? Thanks.